# Why does SVG with width = 0 and height = 0 take layout space?

Tags: html, css, svg

Could you explain why does the first SVG in the following example take layout space even though it has `width="0"` and `height="0"`?

Is it possible to style it in a way that won't affect the layout?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px
}

#blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="blue" width="0" height="0"></svg>
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#blue` has not defined the `display` property, so it defaults to `inline`, which according [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=example) says:  "inline | The element generates one or more inline element boxes."

If you set the display to something like `block`, you will see that it takes up no additional space:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px
}

#blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}

#red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="blue" width="0" height="0"></svg>
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```

Of course, if you want to hide it, `display: none` is the way to go.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. One can clearly see it by running the code snippet - small blue rectangle is visible - because of the 1px border.

Comment: Yes, but it takes up no additional space compared to the question, which takes up 102x121 px. 0x0 px surrounded by 1px border is 2x2 px, so you should expect to see it when a border is defined. If you do an inspect of this element you will see that it is 2x2 px sized. Try to set border to 0px, and you will see that it is effectively hidden from view, but as I explain, at that point it is better practice to hide it completely with `display: none`.

Answer (score 2):

Use display: none; property to not display the element.
Also do not use same ID for two elements(You have used ID "red" for 2 SVGs).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px
}

#blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: none;
}

.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="blue" width="0" height="0"></svg>
  <svg class="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, setting `width` and `height` effectively makes the element disappear **visually**, it is still however being accounted for in the **flow of the page**. The reason you are still seeing it is because you are giving it a border of 1px all around, hence the blue dot. If you remove the `border` rule, it will disappear, but like I said, it is still in the flow of the page, to completely take it out of the page flow, set `display` to `none`

**Remove** `border` rule for `#blue` => blue dot gone, but it is still being taken into the flow of the page

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px
}

#blue {
  /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
}

#red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="blue" width="0" height="0"></svg>
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```

Setting `display` to `none` => no longer takes up space

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 30px
}

#blue {
 border: 1px solid blue;
 display: none;
}

#red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg id="blue" width="0" height="0"></svg>
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <svg id="red" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</div>
```